# Can the last state of a mobile webpage be saved?

Tags: javascript, java

For a mobile website that returns results based on the user's location or inputs: if the user closes the tab or browser, is there a way to allow the user to reopen a saved (cached?) state from the last location search performed if they do not have internet connectivity?

Is it better to use an app instead of a mobile website for this type of functionality?

Comment: Caching is a job of web browser. When you close the browser all the cached data will be cleared. I feel developing your own app will be the right solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).